# Weird behavior of LaTeX-section-label for chapter

Tags: auctex

The default value of LaTeX-section-label is:

```
(("part" . "part:")
 ("chapter" . "chap:")
 ("section" . "sec:")
 ("subsection" . "sec:")
 ("subsubsection" . "sec:"))
```

However, *for chapter*, when typing C-c C-s, we get cha instead of chap:.

```
\chapter{asdf}
\label{cha:asdf}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If reftex is enabled and the variable `reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX` is not nil the value of `LaTeX-section-label`is ignored and `reftex-section-prefixes` is used. Its default value is

```
((0 . "part:")
 (1 . "cha:")
 (t . "sec:"))
```